# Why after wrapping function that return object in useMemo I get warning about non function?

Tags: reactjs

I have this function and pass it to component but after useMemo wrapper it says me that modalComponentsData is not function

```
  const modalComponentsData = useMemo(() => {
    return [
      { name: 'name', placeholder: 'Company name' },
    ]
  }, [])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`useMemo` calls the function it gets to produce the value. You need `useCallback`.

```
  const modalComponentsData = useCallback(() => {
    return [
      { name: 'name', placeholder: 'Company name' },
    ]
  }, [])
```

Or

```
  const modalComponentsData = useMemo(() => () => {
    return [
      { name: 'name', placeholder: 'Company name' },
    ]
  }, [])
```